# Yii framework- CDbCriteria using joins

Tags: php, yii

I want to perform a query with join in Yii. But what happened is that i get an Internal Server 
Error. I want to perform a query of searching items by it's tag group.

This is the query that I want to perform using yii:

```
    select i.id as id, i.title as title, i.content as content from tbl_tags t
    join tbl_items i on t.item_id = i.id
    where t.tag_group_id = (value) and i.item_id = (value)
    group by t.ref_id;
```

And this is how i did it in Yii using `CDbCriteria` :

```
        public function getItemsListByTagGroup( . . .){

            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->select = 'i.id as id, i.title as title, i.content as content i.date_updated as date_updated';
            $criteria->join = 'join tbl_tag t on i.id = t.item_id';
            $criteria -> addCondition('t.tag_group_id = ' . $tag_group_id);
            $criteria -> addCondition('t.reference_type = ' . $ref_type);
            $criteria -> addCondition('t.tag_group_id = ' . $id);
            $criteria -> addCondition('i.item_type = ' . $item_type);
            $criteria -> addCondition('i.item_id  = ' .$item_id);
            $criteria -> addCondition('i.status = "active"');

            $item_list = Items::model() -> findAll($criteria);

            $item_list_data = array();
            foreach ($templates_list as $listdata => $data) {
                $columns = array();
                $columns['Title'] = $data['title'];
                $columns['Content'] = $data['content'];
                $columns['Date Updated'] = $data['date_updated'];
                $columns['id'] = $data['id'];

                $item_list_data[] = $columns;
            }
            return $item_list_data;
        }
```

The models by the way are generated.

But I don't know what I miss or something.
Is there anything you can help?
Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably have an undefined variable, although it's hard to tell because you have obscured the function definition. I strongly suggest you find your error logs and look at them. Internal Server errors are usually the easiest thing to fix, as they tend to be (in my experience) simple typos. You need to read your error logs though to find out where the problem is.

Comment: we need to see the server error

Comment: the error is in join part of criteria, see my answer

Comment: oh okay, i'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

column from **Items** table by default will have alias of **t**, so for pointing id column, you should **t.id , t.title ,...**
and after all you should specify join type,

I recommend to use first approach:

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('i.id as id, i.title as title, i.content as content')
    ->from('tbl_tags t')
    ->join('tbl_items i' , 't.item_id = i.id')
    ->where('t.tag_group_id = :value1' , array(':value1' => $value1))
    ->andWhere('i.item_id = :value2' , array('value2' => $value2))
    ->group('t.ref_id')->queryAll(); // this will be returned as an array of arrays
```

second

, and when your getting data with active record, you can't get data back, as another column that is not in models list of properties, try this

```
  public function getItemsListByTagGroup( . . .){

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = 'i.id , i.title , i.content , i.date_updated'; // if these columns are not in model, won't get fetched
        $criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN tbl_items i on i.id = t.item_id'; // incorrect table join was in here
        $criteria -> addCondition('t.tag_group_id = ' . $tag_group_id);
        $criteria -> addCondition('t.reference_type = ' . $ref_type);
        $criteria -> addCondition('t.tag_group_id = ' . $id);
        $criteria -> addCondition('i.item_type = ' . $item_type);
        $criteria -> addCondition('i.item_id  = ' .$item_id);
        $criteria -> addCondition('i.status = "active"');

        $item_list = Items::model() -> findAll($criteria); // this will be fetched as an array of objects

        $item_list_data = array();
        foreach ($templates_list as $listdata => $data) { 
            $columns = array();
            $columns['Title'] = $data->title;
            $columns['Content'] = $data->content;
            $columns['Date Updated'] = $data->date_updated;
            $columns['id'] = $data->id;

            $item_list_data[] = $columns;
        }
        return $item_list_data;
    }
```

Comment: still the same.. i got nothing.

Comment: is it necessary to specify relations in the Models if i used JOINS?

Comment: if you want to use active records relations, you can use "with", otherwise you have to use typical join